# Object Construction with nested m:n structure in jq

Tags: jq

I have this json

```
 {
  "objectEntries": [
    {
      "objectType": {
        "name": "Test"
      },
      "attributes": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "objectTypeAttributeId": 8,
          "objectAttributeValues": [
            {
              "referencedObject": {
                "id": 17,
                "label": "TestTest",
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "id": 20,
                    "objectTypeAttributeId": 11,
                    "objectAttributeValues": [
                      {
                        "value": "bli"
                      }
                    ],
                    "objectId": 12
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 21,
                    "objectTypeAttributeId": 13,
                    "objectAttributeValues": [
                      {
                        "value": "blo"
                      }
                    ],
                    "objectId": 14
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 22,
                    "objectTypeAttributeId": 15,
                    "objectAttributeValues": [
                     {
                      "referencedObject": {
                        "id": 30,
                        "label": "TestTest",
                        "attributes": [
                          {
                            "id": 35,
                            "objectTypeAttributeId": 36,
                            "objectAttributeValues": [
                              {
                                "value": "bli"
                              }
                            ],
                            "objectId": 37
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 38,
                            "objectTypeAttributeId": 39,
                            "objectAttributeValues": [
                              {
                                "value": "blo"
                              }
                            ],
                            "objectId": 40
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                    "objectId": 16
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 16,
          "objectTypeAttributeId": 8,
          "objectAttributeValues": [
            {
              "referencedObject": {
                "id": 17,
                "label": "TestTest",
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "id": 20,
                    "objectTypeAttributeId": 11,
                    "objectAttributeValues": [
                      {
                        "value": "bli"
                      }
                    ],
                    "objectId": 12
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 21,
                    "objectTypeAttributeId": 13,
                    "objectAttributeValues": [
                      {
                        "value": "blo"
                      }
                    ],
                    "objectId": 14
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 22,
                    "objectTypeAttributeId": 15,
                    "objectAttributeValues": [
                     {
                      "referencedObject": {
                        "id": 30,
                        "label": "TestTest",
                        "attributes": [
                          {
                            "id": 35,
                            "objectTypeAttributeId": 36,
                            "objectAttributeValues": [
                              {
                                "value": "xxx"
                              }
                            ],
                            "objectId": 37
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 38,
                            "objectTypeAttributeId": 39,
                            "objectAttributeValues": [
                              {
                                "value": "yyy"
                              }
                            ],
                            "objectId": 40
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                    "objectId": 16
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want this result.

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "attribute36": "bli",
  "attribute39": "blo"
}
{
  "name": "Test",
  "attribute36": "xxx",
  "attribute39": "yyy"
}
```

But what I get is this

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "attribute36": "bli",
  "attribute39": "blo"
}
{
  "name": "Test",
  "attribute36": "bli",
  "attribute39": "yyy"
}
{
  "name": "Test",
  "attribute36": "xxx",
  "attribute39": "blo"
}
{
  "name": "Test",
  "attribute36": "xxx",
  "attribute39": "yyy"
}
```

The jq query I came up with

```
jq '.objectEntries[] | {"name": .objectType.name, "attribute36": .attributes | .[] | select(.objectTypeAttributeId==8) | .objectAttributeValues[].referencedObject.attributes | .[] | select(.objectTypeAttributeId==15) | .objectAttributeValues[].referencedObject.attributes | .[] | select(.objectTypeAttributeId==36) |  .objectAttributeValues | .[] | .value, "attribute39": .attributes | .[] | select(.objectTypeAttributeId==8) | .objectAttributeValues[].referencedObject.attributes | .[] | select(.objectTypeAttributeId==15) | .objectAttributeValues[].referencedObject.attributes | .[] | select(.objectTypeAttributeId==39) |  .objectAttributeValues | .[] | .value}' stackoverflow.json
```

You can see the problem also on jqplay https://jqplay.org/s/NjqEy7wvQE

The goal is to extract certain fields on the different jsonpath depths into a new, flat json object, per toplevel json object, where toplevel are the objects under `objectEntries[]`

Comment: Post your requirement, what is that you are trying to achieve? i.e. logic behind your desired result

Comment: Why 36, 39 alone?

Comment: The object construction logic is still not clear

Comment: name, attribute36, attribute39 are the values of my interest in the array of objects in objectEntries. I need to extract them to be able to create a csv out of these 3 key:value pairs. The attributeId is unique and I select in the nested objects my values of interest by the attributeId

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the jq query in the Q, we can define two useful functions:

```
def attributes:
  [ .attributes[]
    | select(.objectTypeAttributeId==8)
    | .objectAttributeValues[].referencedObject.attributes[]
    | select(.objectTypeAttributeId==15)
    | .objectAttributeValues[].referencedObject.attributes[] ] ;


def to_o:
   { ("attribute" + (.objectTypeAttributeId|tostring)): first(.objectAttributeValues[].value)};
```

And we see that

```
.objectEntries[] | attributes[] | to_o
```

yields:

```
{"attribute36":"bli"}
{"attribute39":"blo"}
{"attribute36":"xxx"}
{"attribute39":"yyy"}
```

This is where the original question becomes a bit difficult to understand.  I'm going to assume the intent is to group these objects together without loss of information and without introducing arrays.

At any rate, the following filter does produce the desired result:

```
.objectEntries[]
| .objectType.name as $name
| foreach ((attributes[] | to_o), null ) as $o ({};
     if $o == null then .emit = .object
     elif .object|has($o|keys_unsorted[0])
     then .emit=.object | .object=$o
     else .emit=null | .object += $o
     end;
     select(.emit) | .emit)
| {$name} + .
```